# How to render Ckeditor data in next js app

Tags: ckeditor

[Ckeditor Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th2HR.jpg)

I am building a Blog with Next JS, which Fetches Data from a Laravel Rest API, I have done everything fine but when I try to fetch data from Ckeditor field it prints as it is, I have tried multiple Rich Text Markdown Packages within my app but the same problem continues. Output is shown in the Image Above.
Kindly tell me What should i do now ??

```html
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../../styles/BlogSingle.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image'
import SidebarBlogs from './SidebarBlogs'
import { BlogsBelow } from './BlogsBelow'


export default function BlogSingle({blog, blogs}) {
  return (
      <>
        <div className='container' id={styles.Container}>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-4 col-sm-4'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <h1 className={styles.BlogTitle}>{blog.title}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <Image src={blog.image.url} width={850} height={500} alt={blog.slug}></Image>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row' id={styles.PaddingBelowImage}>
                            <div className='col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-3'>
                                <div id={styles.AuthDet}>
                                    <Image src={blog.created_by.profile.thumbnail} width={70} height={50} alt={blog.created_by.name}></Image>
                                    <div className={styles.AuthTextSec}>
                                        <p className={styles.AuthName}>{blog.created_by.name}</p>
                                        <time dateTime='13-11-2021' className={styles.AuthTime}>{blog.created_at}</time>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-3'>
                                <div id={styles.AuthDet}>
                                    <i className='bi bi-bookmark'></i>
                                    <i className='bi bi-link-45deg'></i>
                                    <i className='bi bi-whatsapp'></i>          
                                    <i className='bi bi-facebook'></i>
                                    <i className='bi bi-instagram'></i>
                                    <i className='bi bi-twitter'></i>
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row' id={styles.BlogContent}>   
                        {blog.desc}
                        {/* <CKEditor
                            editor={ Editor }
                            config={ editorConfiguration }
                            data={ blog.desc }
                            
                        />                             */}
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1'>
                        <div className="vl"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <p className={styles.YouLike}>{"You May Also Like"}</p>
                        </div>
                        <SidebarBlogs blogs={blogs}></SidebarBlogs>                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.HideOnMobile}>
                <p>{"Featured Stories"}</p>            
            </div>            
            <hr></hr>
            <BlogsBelow blogs={blogs}></BlogsBelow>
```